# Updating ContentResolver to get updated file count

Tags: android, android-file, android-contentresolver, mediastore, storage-access-framework

I am deleting few files using `Storage Access Framework` from External Storage in Marshmallow version of Android. I need to show the count of different kinds of files available in the External Storage. I am getting proper count for Internal Storage, but for External Storage I am not getting updated file count for Videos. Whenever I open an inbuilt File Manager and then get back to the App, it updates the File count properly which means I need to call some kind of method to update the ContentResolver.

Here's how I am getting the count of Videos in External Storage

```
private long[] findSize(StorageSource source, FileTypes type) {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(CONTENT_URI_COMMON);
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.SIZE };
        String selection = getSelectionQuery(type);
        String[] selectionArgs = {};
        long total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        String sortOrder = null;
        Cursor allExtMediaFiles = populateQueries(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        synchronized (allExtMediaFiles) {
            if (allExtMediaFiles != null) {
                if (allExtMediaFiles.moveToFirst())

                    do {
                        if (isValidFamily(allExtMediaFiles.getString(0), source)) {
                            total = total + allExtMediaFiles.getLong(1);
                            count++;
                        }
                    } while (allExtMediaFiles.moveToNext());
                allExtMediaFiles.close();
            }
        }
        return new long[] { total, count };
    }

private Cursor populateQueries(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) {
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(cr,uri);
        return cursor;
    }
```

I have tried to get correct file count using different methods including calling `cursor.setNotificationUri(cr,uri);`, `notifyChange()` on `ContentResolver` and also using `MediaScanner` too. Here's the code I am using after I have deleted the video file -

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
                    getActivity().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getActivity(), new String[] {
                                    path},
                            null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                                public void onScanCompleted(String scanPath, Uri scanUri)
                                {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Path "+scanPath+" uri"+scanUri.toString());
                                }
                            });
```

Here `path` is the String Uri from `DocumentFile` which just got deleted using `Storage Access Framework`. I have tried using this also in the `notifyChange()` method.

So how can I update the ContentResolver to return me updated File Count?

Comment: "Here path is the String Uri from DocumentFile" -- that is not going to work. `MediaScannerConnection` does not work with a `Uri`. It works with a file path, and is only used when you are the one responsible for managing the filesystem. In this case, you are not, and therefore you do not have a file path. "So how can I update the ContentResolver to return me updated File Count?" -- that is the responsibility of the `DocumentsProvider` handling your delete request through the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am calling just `DocumentFile#delete()`. Do I need to do something else to make it update the `ContentResolver`?

Comment: The `ContentResolver` is not the problem. The `MediaStore` is the problem. You shouldn't need to do anything to update the `MediaStore`. Again, that's really the responsibility of the `DocumentsProvider`. More to the point, I do not know of any reliable and efficient way that you *could* update the `MediaStore`. For external storage, I suspect that some people tell the `MediaStore` to re-scan all of external storage, which is inefficient and may not be that quick. However, that won't be an option for removable storage (e.g., micro SD, USB OTG drive).

Comment: So, I suppose it's an issue with the device manufacturer, because I have tested with ES Explorer and it's facing the same issue. But if I check with system's own default File Manager, then it's updating it properly and if I get back to my app, it shows proper count now. So probably the default file manager is using some private API to do this.

Comment: Pre-installed apps can be given extra rights by the device manufacturer. Pre-installed file managers often can work directly with the filesystem for external storage and removable storage, whereas user-installed file managers cannot work with removable storage. Apps that manage the filesystem are responsible for telling the `MediaStore` about changes to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

try this line after delete function

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

(above solution doesn't seem to work since android 4.4)

for DATA :

```
MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA
```

also you can try using this

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(fileDeleted)));
```

see this link for a (kind of) detailed method:

http://sandersdenardi.com/querying-and-removing-media-from-android-mediastore/

also keep in mind that:

> All queries and deletes (and inserts and updates for that matter) block until the underlying transaction completes. You should perform these operations on the ContentResolver asynchronously on a separate thread. While a delete on the MediaStore shouldn’t take a significant amount of time at all, it will block the UI if performed on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I have tried all of these options. They doesn't seem t work, except the method mentioned in the blog post. I'll try that and will let you know if it works.